# How to remove the intersection of two rectangles without removing the background?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm drawing on a canvas, I want to remove the intersection of two rectangles without removing the background.

[image: delete only intersection between the yellow and blue]

the red rectangle would be my background, I just want to remove the intersection between the yellow and blue rectangle without removing the red. If I use the property `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";` the background (color red) is deleted.

[image: background deleted]

How can I achieve this?

My code:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 75, 50);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.fillRect(59,30,75,50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `destination-over` before you draw the red shape and put that after the other content.

Per MDN: "New shapes are drawn behind the existing canvas content."

So you use `destination-out` for the exclusion and then add the red shape in behind.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 75, 50);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.fillRect(59, 30, 75, 50);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
```

```html
<canvas width="150" height="150" id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a copy of the background before you add anything more to the image.

To copy the canvas

```
function copyImage(image) { // image can be any image source
    const copy = document.createElement("canvas");
    copy.width = image.width;
    copy.height = image.height;
    copy.ctx = copy.getContext("2d");
    copy.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return copy;
}
```

Once you have a copy of the background then you can layer the image.

Steps

- First clear the canvas
- Draw the blue box
- Set `globalCompositeOperation` to `"destination-out"`
- Draw the yellow box
- Set `globalCompositeOperation` to `"destination-over"`
- Draw the background

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Create background
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 100);

// copy background
const bgImage = copyImage(canvas);

// Clear canvas
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);

// Draw the blue box
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(100, 75, 150, 70);

// draw yellow to remove pixels
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.fillRect(150, 50, 150, 70);

// draw background
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);

// copy image util function
function copyImage(img, {width, height} = img) { 
  const c = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"),{width,height}).getContext("2d");
  c.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  return c.canvas;
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 2px solid #000 }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the background to red.